# MS Access engine & Office standard 2010

Tags: .net, ms-access, ms-office

I have a question about the MS Access engine and Office 2010 standard edition.

I have a .net app (32 bits) accessing an .accdb file. It uses .net framework 4. I use the Access Engine Ole db provider (Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0). Development takes place on a computer having a MS Office installation including MS Access.

Now I want to deploy on a computer having Win 7 and Office 2010 standard edition (32 bits). For sure I need to install .Net framework 4.
But I would like to know if I need to install the MS Access Engine redistributable or if this package is already installed with MS Office 2010 standard edition (note: access is not included in the standard edition).

Comment: You can download the Access 2010 Rutime only. See here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-ie/download/details.aspx?id=10910

Comment: You can use the [AceOdbcCheck](https://github.com/gordthompson/AceOdbcCheck) script to see if the Access Database Engine components are already installed on the target machine. If the ODBC components are present then the OLEDB components will be available as well.

Comment: @KostasK. The Access _runtime_ is for applications that require the Access UI including Forms, Reports, etc.  The runtime is not necessary only for ACE / Jet database access via an OLE DB provider.

Comment: My guess is that _no_, the standard Office version will not include all drivers.  It might be likely to find some necessary ODBC components on a systems that has had any application or development components installed which requires ACE / Jet database access.  But the DB engine/driver files are not that large and installing them will ensure that necessary components are all there.  Why not just install it?